# I need a 0.16 in * 0.16 in square to be 70 px * 70 px, what resolution do I render it at?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, gimp, png

I'm rendering a PDF as an image in GIMP, basically I need every 0.16 by 0.16 inch square to be a 70 by 70 pixel square.

What pixels/in resolution do I need to import the PDF as, and how does one work this out?

Comment: You can't do this reliably, as displays with different pixel densities will have a n-by-n pixel box come out different sizes.  However, you can determine what pixel density you need on an ideal display by simply dividing your required number of pixels by your required size in inches - that gives you pixels per inch, which is what you appear to be asking for.

Comment: I'm trying to do the reverse: I have a PDF with vector graphics (in inches), and I need to export it with GIMP so that it produces a bitmap PNG (in pixels). I want 0.16 inches to become 70 pixels, so that a 0.16 inch by 0.16 inch box is 70 pixels by 70 pixels.

Comment: It's still the same calculation - you've established that your required size in inches (from the PDF) is 0.16, and you've also established that your required size in pixels is 70. You therefore want 70 pixels per 0.16 inches, so divide 70 by 0.16, or 437.5. As @Yorik said in the answer he proposed, you can't actually have 437.5 pixels per inch, so you'll have to use either 437 or 438.

Answer (score 1):

That is 70 Pixels Per .16 Inch (pixels per inch or PPI).

(.16) "goes into" (1) 6.25 times.

So that equates to (70 pixels * 6.25) per (.16 inches * 6.25), or 437.5 PPI.

The number of pixels cannot be non-integers (they are quantized point sample "buckets"), so you need to round this to 438 or truncate it to 437. This will mean a slight error.

So then you will take the width and height of the PDF document, in inches, and multiply width and height each by 437px (so if it were a 10x10 inch page, your target image is 4370px by 4370px). You then import the PDF as an image at that exact size (if possible). You then export an image that is exactly those pixel dimensions ignoring any PPI flag during export.

PPI is simply a tag or flag in the header of the file. The only thing that matters is pixels, and pixels are dimensionless point-samples in a raster image.

Comment: I wouldn't have dealt with the "0.16 goes into 1" part; just divide the pixels (70) by the inches (0.16); you'll get the same 437.5. Other than that, yeah, that's what the OP needs to do.

Comment: Right, basically we are converting 1 ratio or fraction to another (`70/.16=x/1` becomes `70/.16*1=x`). Then we do the same with the result (for a 10 inch dimension) `437/1=x/10` becomes `437/1*10=x`